# Show that the minimal number of linear inequalities to determine a bounded polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n+1$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $D\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a polyhedron defined by {$ x:a_i^T x \leq b_i,i=1,\dots,m $}. Show that if $D$ is nonempty and  bounded, then $m$ is at least $n+1$.

To prove this statement, my attempt is to first show that if the number of inequalities $m\leq n-1$, then $D$ cannnot be bounded. It's because we can choose a vector $v$ orthogonal to all $a_i$'s, then any feasible $x$ added by a multiple of $v$ is also feasible. Hence $D$ is unbounded.

So now the question is how to show that when $m=n$, $D$ cannot be bounded. If one of $a_i$'s is orthogonal to the others, we can set $x_\lambda=x-\lambda a_i$ and let $\lambda$ go to infinity. However, I have no clue what to do for the general $a_i$'s.

I think my thought process is not quite systematic, so I welcome anyone to propose a totally different approach so that we can have a better understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you just had $n$ inequalities $a_i^T x \le b_i$.  The $n-1$ vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_{n-1}$ span a space of dimension at most $n-1$, so there is some nonzero vector $v$ such that $a_i^T v = 0$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n-1$.  Suppose
$p$ is a point in $D$: thus $a_i^T p \le b_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$.
If $a_n^T v \le 0$, then $a_i^T (p + t v) \le 0$ for $i = 1 \ldots, n$ and all $t \ge 0$, so the ray $p + t v$ for $t \ge 0$ is contained in $D$, and $D$ is not bounded.  Same with $p + t v$ for $t \le 0$ if $a_n^T v \ge 0$.